# Raspberry hangs when transferring files to usb disk if it is connected to the router

Tags: file-sharing

I have attached an usb disk to my Raspberry Pi, mounted it under /mnt/disk1 and shared through Samba with the name "Disk1".
The Pi is connected to my home network through an ethernet cable to my modem/router, a Netgear DGN3500.
From my MacBook, connected to the same network through wifi, I see the shared disk and I can navigate files and folders inside. But as soon as I try to copy some files to the Pi, after a few minutes the Pi hangs: the transfer is interrupted, the ssh prompt I keep open closes and I cannot ping it no more: host is down. This happens while copying through the samba share, but also using scp: after a moment, the Pi freezes, and I have to reboot it removing the power cable.
But if I connect the Pi through an ethernet directly to my MacBook, this does not happen: I am able to copy large amount of files from the Mac to the Pi, using samba or ssh, without any issue.

The Raspberry hangs only when copying from the MacBook to the shared disk. Transferring files from the shared disk to the MacBook works without any issue.

Could this problem be related in some way to my router? Anyone has experienced a behavior like this?

Comment: I've experienced some weird problems too with my home network and the raspberry. mine didn't always manage to do a reboot, it just stuck with static blinking leds. I managed to point it down to my network being charged from somewhere. After plugging everything (EVERY device in your network) out, it went away. Now I don't know your network, but you can try!

Comment: The Rasperry is the only devise attached to the router with a cable, everything else, laptops, phones and the tablet is connected using wifi.

Comment: have you tried switching the pi's power supply? It should at least have 800mah-1A

Comment: The power supply I have is 1.5A, I think it should be ok.

Comment: you said, "But if I connect the Pi through an Ethernet directly to my Mac Book, this does not happen". By that you meant a complete wired network?

Comment: A direct link with a an ethernet cable between my laptop and the Pi, without anything else in between.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have not resolved it yet. I'm still getting the connection hangs :|

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No. After a while I have bought a small wifi adapter for the Pi and then everything started working correctly.